# Remove outlier (using zscore) when input contains nan >

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have the following `dataframe`:

```
   COL1  COL2  COL3   COL4
0   1.0    10    10  15000
1   2.0  1150    20  10020
2   3.0  1160  3035  10035
3   4.0  1117     2  10055
4   NaN  1131    50  10067
```

I want to remove the outlier using zscore.

I tried to do it with this line code:

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df, nan_policy='omit'))<1.8).all(axis=1)]
```

but I'm getting warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df, nan_policy='omit'))<1.8).all(axis=1)]
```

And result:

```
   COL1  COL2  COL3   COL4
1   2.0  1150    20  10020
3   4.0  1117     2  10055
```

I'm confused:

1. Why I'm getting warnning if I set `nan_policy='omit'` ?
2. I thought my code will preserved the rows: 1, 3, 4
   Why I didn't get that output ? (If we are ignoring nan ?)

Full code:

```
dict = {'COL1': [1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan],
        'COL2': [10, 1150, 1160, 1117, 1131],
        'COL3': [10, 20, 3035, 2, 50],
        'COL4': [15000, 10020, 10035, 10055, 10067]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df.head())
zscore = np.abs(stats.zscore(df))
print(zscore)
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df, nan_policy='omit'))<1.8).all(axis=1)]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nan_policy='omit'`ignores the `NaN`value to calculate mean and standard deviation, however when calculating the zscore, `NaN` values will be mapped to `NaN`

```
np.abs(stats.zscore(df, nan_policy='omit')).round(2)
# array([[1.34, 2.  , 0.51, 2.  ],
#    [0.45, 0.52, 0.5 , 0.51],
#    [0.45, 0.55, 2.  , 0.5 ],
#    [1.34, 0.45, 0.52, 0.49],
#    [ nan, 0.48, 0.48, 0.49]]) #There is NaN value here
```

Then `np.abs(stats.zscore(df, nan_policy='omit')) < 1.8` will trhow the warning, and keep in mind that:

```
np.nan < 1.8  # False
```

You can use numpys [`nan_to_num`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) to replace with a 0:

```
df = df[(np.nan_to_num(np.abs(stats.zscore(df, nan_policy='omit')),0) < 1.8).all(axis=1)]
df

#   COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
# 1 2.0     1150    20      10020
# 3 4.0     1117    2       10055
# 4 NaN     1131    50      10067
```

Comment: Replace nan with 0, changes the mean and std values, so it will be better to ignore the nan

Comment: You are ignoring the nan to calculate the mean and std using `nan_policy='omit'` but you need to change nan to 0 if you want to ignore them in the `all` method. Please check the answer and let me know any questions.